# How to reset/revert Heroku Config?

Tags: heroku

Since each time you add a key/value using `heroku config:add` it returns a version, is it possible to revert to an older version?

If not, is it possible to clear all of the `heroku config`, since I've got a local `.env` that I'd like to push, but it does not clean out the other variables.

Reason I cannot use `heroku config:unset` is because of some bug, I was able to put an empty key there.

`: true`

Not I can't get rid of it, and the build keeps failing -_-'

** UPDATE **

just found `heroku releases`

Answer (score 2):

Running `heroku rollback` would rollback to the previous release, and you can also specify an older version with it. The full heroku docs have more on this - https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/releases#rollback

Comment: What if I absolutely need not to rollback the entire application ? I need to revert only two config vars: I unfortunately completely forgot their older values. But I can't afford to rollback the entire app. Any ideas ?

Comment: @user3387633 you can inspect the config vars of older releases with the `heroku release:info ...` command.

Answer (score 0):

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/releases#rollback

It will give more details of release.
$ heroku releases:info v24

v24 is your release name, which can vary accordingly.